# How do you create Solr Queries with wildcard seaches and scoring, fuzzy search, distance searching and other features

Tags: solr

I am trying to build a search over my domain with solr, and I am having trouble producing a keyword search that fulfils our requirements. My issue;

When my users search, the requirement is that the search must return results with partial token matches. For example:

Consider the text field: "CA-1234-ABCD California project"

The following keyword searches (what the user puts in the search field) should match this field:

``
"California"

"Cali"

"CA-1234-ABCD"

"ABCD"

"ABCD-1234"
``
etc.

With a text_en field (as configured in the example schema), the tokenization, stemming and grammar processing will allow non-wildcard searches to work for partial words/tokens in many cases, but Solr still seems limited to exact token match in many situations. For example, the following query does not match:

`name:cali`

The only way I have found to get the user experience that is required is to use a wildcard search:

`name:*cali*`

The problem with this is that tf scoring (and it seems other functionality like fuzzy searches) don't work with a wildcard search.

The question is, is there a way to get partial token matching (for all tokens not just those that have common stems/etc.) while retaining tf scoring and other advanced query functionality?

My best workaround at the moment is a query that includes both wildcard and non-wildcard clauses, such as:

`name:cali OR name:*cali*`

but I don't know if that is a good strategy here. Does SOLR provide a way?

Comment: I'm not sure if you only want prefix matches (i.e. just `cali` should match `california`, while `forn` doesn't match - but the ngramfilter and edgengramfilter allows you to properly generate tokens for any submatches in a given token. I'd try to limit the shortest token size to avoid having `a`, `b`, `c` etc. as tokens in every document as they won't do much good for neither user experience or scoring. That way `name:cali` would match as you expect. You can then have these chains in different fields, so that you can score `name` and `name_ngram` differently (score exact hits higher).

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh that seems like what I am looking for.